# Changing spaces with "prxchange", but not all spaces

Tags: regex, sas

I need to change the spaces in my text to underscores, but only the spaces that are between words, not the ones between digits, so, for an example

```
"The quick brown fox 99 07 3475"
```

Would become

```
"The_quick_brown_fox 99 07 3475"
```

I tried using this in a data step:

```
mytext = prxchange('s/\w\s\w/_/',-1,mytext);
```

But the result was not what i wanted

```
"Th_uic_row_ox 99 07 3475"
```

Any ideas on what i could do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing
"W W"
to
"_"
when you want to change
"W W"
to
"W_W"

so
prxchange('s/(\w)\s(\w)/$1_$2/',-1,mytext);

Full example:

```
 data test;
mytext='The quick brown fox 99 07 3475';
newtext = prxchange('s/([A-Za-z])\s([A-Za-z])/$1_$2/',-1,mytext);
put _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Data One ;
X = "The quick brown fox 99 07 3475" ;
Y = PrxChange( 's/(?<=[a-z])\s+(?=[a-z])/_/i' , -1 , X ) ;
Put X= Y= ;
Run ;
```

Comment: Yes, that's a bit simpler than my solution.  I must learn the finer details of PERL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CALL PRXNEXT function to find the position of each match, then use the SUBSTR function to replace the space with an underscore.  I've changed your regular expression as \w matches any alphanumeric character, so it should include spaces between numbers.  I'm not sure how you got your result using that expression.
Anyway, the code below should give you what you want.

```
data have;
mytext='The quick brown fox 99 07 3475';
_re=prxparse('/[a-z]\s[a-z]/i'); /* match a letter followed by a space followed by a letter, ignore case */
_start=1 /* starting position for search */;
call prxnext(_re,_start,-1,mytext,_position,_length); /* find position of 1st match */
    do while(_position>0); /* loop through all matches */
        substr(mytext,_position+1,1)='_'; /* replace ' ' with '_' for matches */
        _start=_start-2; /* prevents the next start position jumping 3 ahead (the length of the regex search string) */
        call prxnext(_re,_start,-1,mytext,_position,_length); /* find position of next match */ 
end;
drop _: ;
run;
```